# Virtual functions and std::function?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++17, virtual-functions

Consider the following code in C++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct base
{
    base() {std::cout << "base::base" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~base() {std::cout << "base::~base" << std::endl;}
    virtual void operator()() {std::cout << "base::operator()" << std::endl;}
};

struct derived1: base
{
    derived1() {std::cout << "derived1::derived1" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~derived1() {std::cout << "derived1::~derived1" << std::endl;}
    virtual void operator()() {std::cout << "derived1::operator()" << std::endl;}
};

struct derived2: base
{
    derived2() {std::cout << "derived2::derived2" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~derived2() {std::cout << "derived2::~derived2" << std::endl;}
    virtual void operator()() {std::cout << "derived2::operator()" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    base* ptr1 = new derived1();
    base* ptr2 = new derived2();
    std::function f1(*ptr1);
    std::function f2(*ptr2);
    std::invoke(*ptr1);     // calls derived1::operator()
    std::invoke(*ptr2);     // calls derived2::operator()
    std::invoke(f1);        // calls base::operator()
    std::invoke(f2);        // calls base::operator()
    delete ptr1;
    delete ptr2;
    return 0;
}
```

`std::function` does not seem to do the right thing with virtual functions. Would there be any way to make `std::invoke(*ptrN)` and `std::invoke(fN)` behave the same way? Or would there be any way to create a new function wrapper that would deal with virtual functions?

Comment: `std::function` **copies** the functor it receives. You pass it a `base`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: You should also prefer `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate. The "why" is not the focus of the post. The focus is how make it work.

Comment: What did you use for compiling? (compiler/version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `std::reference_wrapper`, or the convenient `std::ref`. `std::function` will use SOO (small object optimization) in this case, so the object won't be copied/moved (avoiding the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)). However, you won't get the deduction guide so you need to specify the template arguments.

```
std::function<void()> f1(std::ref(*ptr1));
std::function<void()> f2(std::ref(*ptr2));
```

Comment: The avoidance of slicing is not by small object optimization, that does exactly what it claims to do: optimize.

Comment: Why are deduction guides failing with std::reference_wrapper?

Comment: @Vincent - Because the reference wrapper doesn't have `operator()`

Comment: @StoryTeller It does: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()

Comment: @Vincent - A templated forwarding one. The deduction guide depends on the `operator()` being a member function, not a template of one. Roughly speaking.

Comment: @Vincent http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/deduction_guides explains it well. `&F::operator()` needs to be well-formed in an unevaluated context. As `std::reference_wrapper<T>::operator()` is a function template, you can't just take the address of it. It *could* still work if `std::reference_wrapper<T>`'s definition was changed to include a non-template `operator()` in a similar way as that deduction guide: if and only if `&T::operator()` is well-formed in an unevaluated context.

Answer (score 3):

> Would there be any way to make std::invoke(*ptrN) and std::invoke(fN) behave the same way? Or would there be any way to create a new function wrapper that would deal with virtual functions?

`std::function` copies its arguments to be able to run later, as already suggested in the comments to the question.
Therefore you can just avoid slicing objects and copy something else that is able to deal correctly with polymorphism.
As an example:

```
std::function f1([ptr1](){ (*ptr1)(); });
std::function f2([ptr2](){ (*ptr2)(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't pass instance of derived class to `std::function`, instead, it constructs new base object by copying instance of derived, which is passed to `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to avoid the slicing copy made by `std::function` is to *bind* the method `operator()` to the object it should be applied.

So you could write:

```
auto f1 = std::bind(&base::operator(), ptr1);
auto f2 = std::bind(&base::operator(), ptr2);
std::invoke(f1);                          // calls derived1::operator()
std::invoke(f2);                          // calls derived2::operator()
```

Comment: Invoke can perfectly well "call the object pointed to by ptr1" (it will automatically invoke `operator()`, which was also shown in the example). The real problem is that `std::function` creates a slicing copy of that object - it stores a `base` because the passed in type was a `base`. You just need to avoid that copy. There are several ways to accomplish that: `std::bind()`, `std::ref()` and using lambda's are all acceptible answers.

Comment: @oisyn: I'm too old for those semantics :-( I've edited my post... Thank you for the feedback.